# My dbh.php code is not working

Tags: php, database, parsing, syntax

Im setting up a website at home using abyss web server. I have a mysqli database on my machine that I use. I wrote a database handler so that I can connect my php code to my database. This is what it looks like:

[image]

I renamed the password and database in the code to xxx for privacy concerns.

When I attempted to test out my form (Just simply having it echo the values I entered right back at me.), it spit this goofy error at me

[image]

So what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Include your code and error here, do not link to images.

Comment: That's because you're missing semicolon `;` after `... mysqli_connect_error())`.

Comment: You forgot a `;` at the end of your `die()` line (line 5).  The error is not goofy, it tells you exactly what's going on.

Comment: Don't include the screenshot of your code, or error. [Edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41527211/edit) and include your code and the error in **textual** form.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are missing a semicolon `;` at the end of line 5

(note: please include code properly formatted instead of images. It's easier if someone wants to show the fix from the code you provided)

Comment: This adds nothing that wasn't already addressed in the comments.  Further, do not provide answers to such low-quality questions. This should be closed, with the `simple typographical error` reason...

Comment: @cale_b as I was writing the answer, no comments were visible yet